# How to stop function execution for a while in a for loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have for loop in which I wrote queries:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  (function(result, type, i) {
    var sleepTime = 0;
    if (i % 10 === 0) {
      sleepTime = 3000;
      console.log('reached');
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      prepareCache(i, result, req, res, type);
    }, sleepTime);
  })(result, type, i);
}
```

I want to stop executing the `prepareCache` function for 3 sec on every 10 number of i. I.e is 10, 20, 30 but with the code I wrote it's not working. Can anyone please suggest me help?

Comment: if timeout for multiples of 10, shouldnt the settimeout function be inside if(i%10) loop

Answer (score 0):

You should choose `Promise`. To embed promise in loop you can check the following example of code:

```
(function loop(i) {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const timeout = Math.random() * 1000;
        setTimeout( () => {
            console.log(i);
            resolve(); // resolve it!
        }, timeout);
    }).then( () => i >= 10 || loop(i+1) );
})(0);
```